# Oracle index access behaviour

Tags: oracle

I have a table customer having fields customer_id, customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_address.

I have created index cust_index on customer

```
CREATE INDEX cust_index
ON customer (UPPER(customer_id));
```

I am using query as

```
select * from customer where customer_id=? and customer_fname=?
```

I wants to know is cust_index will be used in my select query?

Comment: For this query no `select * from customer where customer_id=?`
for this yes  `select * from customer where upper(customer_id)=?` 
But it's depends from on many  factors.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz for reply.

Comment: Arkadiusz do you have idea how to check particular query is using any index or not?

Answer (score 2):

The function based index used only if where clause signature fully matchs the index signature. If you request the compiled index body you'll see that it compiled in uppercase to be usefull for compare with compiled query statements. To know which query which indexes use you can make select from system view `v$sql_plan_statistics_all` providing appropriate sql_id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to google for "oracle cost based optimizer" and explain plan .

```
explain plan for your_query_here
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

This'll display hipotethical for query.

Or run a query and

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR)
```

It'll display real plan for last cursor/query.

if oracle've choose cursor to access data in  explain plan appear `"INDEX somthing SCAN index_name "`